# Redirect console logging output to flask-socketio

Tags: python, logging, flask, flask-socketio

I log events to console via the Python `logging` module.
I also want to send that log messages via socket-io (flask) to a client.
The following approach was only partly successful.

```py
from flask.ext.socketio import send

fmt_str = '%(asctime)s - %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt_str)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=fmt_str)

logger = logging.getLogger("")

class SocketIOHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        send(record.getMessage())

sio = SocketIOHandler()
logger.addHandler(sio)
```

I get the result in the browser, but still get

```
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

for each send call on the console. I think the context for the send call is not availible... What is a useful way to deal with that problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `send` and `emit` functions are context-aware functions that only work from inside an event handler. The equivalent context-free functions are available from the `socketio` instance. Example (making some assumptions about your app that may or may not be true):

```
from app import socketio  # flask.ext.socketio.SocketIO instance

fmt_str = '%(asctime)s - %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt_str)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=fmt_str)

logger = logging.getLogger("")

class SocketIOHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        socketio.send(record.getMessage())

sio = SocketIOHandler()
logger.addHandler(sio)
```

The first line may need to be adapted to the structure of your application, but with this your application will broadcast logs to all the clients.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that also before. It is not working for me... http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=D3x1usXe